# Numerical integration over a surface of a sphere

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration, numerical-methods

[image]

I am integrating a double integral in spherical coordinates over the surface of a sphere in MATLAB numerically. Although I have changed the relative and absolute tolerance I get the feeling that this algorithm never terminates. And when I checked the values of my function that MATLAB had evaluated everything looked fine, no huge oscillations, no singularities.

Do you know whether there are other algorithms that I could use which work faster and still give me reliable results?

So the sphere sits at $(0,0,0)$ and has a radius of $10^{-6}$. Don't be confused that the $y$-component is not shown, I took this one as being fixed in order to plot this.

Okay, maybe I define my problem a little bit better: I want to perform this integration as fast as possible with an accuracy that should be about $10^{-1}$ or $10^{-2}$, this is sufficient. Of course, I thought about adding this lower precision to the integral2 function, but still, this function is so slowly that it is useless for what I am currently doing here.

Comment: You haven't said what algorithm you're using in the first place, which would sort of be useful to know.

Comment: I am using this command http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html

Comment: What are you integrating?

Comment: @RonGordon it is a cumbersome function that you cannot write down(takes about 1s/2s to evaluate it) ( physical origin, Mie-scattering, in order to be precise), but this function should not have any unusual behaviour

Comment: Can you break it down into components, i.e. is this like a partial wave expansion?

Comment: I can provide you with a plot of this function, just a sec

Comment: There you are, so this function is continuous, although it has this sharp increasement in one direction

Comment: Is this a plot of direction cosines?

Comment: what is a direction cosine? no, it is the absolute value of the function i want to integrate in the x-z plane. you must imagine that this function has in one particular direction a very high slope(although still continuous) and in the other directions it is more or less close to zero

Comment: A direction cosine is to a unit sphere as is a cosine or sine is to a unit circle.  Anyway, it is moot because I did not see the scales on the axes.

Comment: @RonGordon , so you do not have a proposal for me, how to integrate this numerically?

Comment: @Lipschitz: no, not yet, not without more info about functional form, etc.

Comment: okay, let me explain how i got this: Mie scattering is done by decomposing the electric and magnetic field into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_spherical_harmonics    now I did this for both the electric and magnetic field and want to integrate over $$\frac{1}{2}\text{Re} \int_0^{2 \pi } \int_0^{pi} E_{\theta} H{\phi}^* - H_{\theta} E_{phi}^* \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi $$.(theta and phi refer to coordinates of the vector of both fields in spherical coordinates) Both the electric and magnetic field have the behaviour, that they show this huge numbers in this one direction.

Comment: (Probably http://www.geog.ucsb.edu/~joel/g266_s10/lecture_notes/chapt04/oh10_4_2/fig_4_12.gif c gives you an impression of the field)

Comment: If you provided your Matlab code we might be able to see if your were doing something that was causing `integral2` to be slow or possibly make the code more efficient. Otherwise, you could try [`quad2d`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quad2d.html) or [this](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/sphere_quad/sphere_quad.html) -I have no idea if it's any good though.

Comment: okay, I upload it

Comment: okay, I discovered that it is impossible to upload something, so if here is anybody who wants to help me and needs my code, he can propose a way to get this

Comment: @horchler Thank you horchler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case that someone is interested in the solution I found: [Lebedev quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebedev_quadrature) solved my question completely (see horchler's comment above).